# codeigniter - get current array position while doing foreach $object->result_array()

Tags: codeigniter

get current array position pointer while doing foreach $object->result_array()

Hi,
consider this, a case.

```
foreach($object->result_array() as $rs)
{
    //how do i display the current array element index that is the iteration index.
    //i want to call a function when the iterator is in the last-1 position.
    // and more specifically i want to use it in this place and not any other for(;;) loops.
    // and even it is an example with other loops then that is fine.
}
```

There should be an option or by using current() function.
I had tried but still i have to do some analysis…
Instead of debugging and tracing the array elements i am posting this thread.

**and above all is it possible to do it with a for loop?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `=> $key` like this to get key as well:

```
foreach($object->result_array() as $rs => $key)
{
   echo $key;
}
```

> and above all is it possible to do it
>   with a for loop?

Yes like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($object->result_array()); $i++)
{
  // your code...
}
```

Comment: Working. Thank you. but...
What you have said is right but it seems that you want just point me some idea instead of giving some more of code.

anyway i got what i want and i have voted you. thank you.

In that code i want $rs which is the current index number that is the array position or the iterator.

and in for loop we need to do $object->result_array[$i]['field']

It figured out both but you can have given like this.
Anyway i tried myself and by this way let us have our analytics sharp.

I assumed from your code and made up this.

Comment: @Jayapal Chandran: That is good news and I answered as much as i could understand your question. It is good to see that you figured it out remaining part yourself and that is always a good thing for a programmer :)

Comment: yeah.
Here is my code.

$list = $object->result_array();
$length = sizeof($list);
foreach($list as $key=>$value)
{
  if ($key==$length-1) echo 'This is the last item';
  if ($key==$length-2) echo 'This is the item before the last item';
}

Comment: I wonder how you were able to post immediately.
Do you have any api for that and if so then please give me a reference i will too implement it in my side so that i can monitor new questions and answers to my questions.

Comment: Why in comments section we cannot post code?
do we have to answer our own question like in the other forums(vbulletin)?

Comment: What i asked was do you have any program to monitor stackover flow to detect latest posts and answers. do you?